# Hubspot: Blog Content listing page issue

Tags: hubspot

In Hubpost I'm using Blog content which have Blog template and Blog listing options.
Everything is fine and configured. When blog webpage is opened then on the list page, some of items do have description on left and some do not.
Inspite the meta description is defined for each blog content.

Answer (score 0):

With "items" did you mean the blog-posts displayed on the listing-page?

The text that appears for a post on the listing-page depends on how the blog post author placed the "More" separator.
If it's right at the top, the following blog-text won't be displayed at the listing page. 
Don't know if this hits your problem ... if it is still an issue maybe you can describe it more detail or post a screenshot.